Generate persistence mapping feature in IntelliJ IDEA has dissapeared?
I have recently upgraded to IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1. I work with the Hibernate framework and I used very often the 'Generate persistence mapping' feature from the Persistence window but it seems that this feature is no longer working.
Maybe has it been replaced by the 'Generate JPA entities' option in the Database window?

Yes, it was replaced by the "Generate JPA entities from DB":

If you need the old feature for some reason, enable the following key in Help | Find Action | Registry:
jpa.generate.persistence.mapping.enabled


Ok, so I understand that this new version is strictly JPA-compliant and will no longer support any hibernate-specific features such as XML files, isn't it?

See https://jpa-buddy.com/guides/generate-or-synchronize-jpa-hibernate-entities/. This functionality is provided by JPA Buddy, which is now a part of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

What I haven't been able to do is to automtically update the persistence unit (hibernate.cfg.xml) with the database connection parameters and the mapped entities. I have browse the documentation in this link but haven't found how to do it with the new options.

Feel free to report an issue for the missing features. Did you try the workaround with the Registry to restore the previous functionality?
